# Using deconvolution method for explanation of model's decision

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I hope you could help me out by explaining me how to use DeconvNet for explanation of model's decision. I'd specifically want to know how one would create heatmaps as shown in this article (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06321.pdf).

I do know how to get features of a specific neuron using DeconvNet, but I'd like to know how we can create heatmaps of features which speak for specific classification. It's clearly doable as shown in the article above and otherwise they wouldn't have compared it to LRP.

Since DeconvNet can't work with FC layers, at least I'm not aware of it, I wonder whether we simply transform FC layers to convolutional ones and then in the last, classifiaction layer we set all neurons' activation values to zero except the one we're interested in and then we would just build DeconvNet on top of it.

Or by the nature of CNNs we can simply take all activation maps of the last convolutional layer in the model as an input to the DeconvNet and that's it.

Thank you, guys.